# how to make UITableViewRowAnimation have delay or slower than standart?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, animation, row

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableViewA;
    DLog(@"%@", self.tableViewA);
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

            DLog(@"MASUK Insert");
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            DLog(@"MASUK Delete");
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            DLog(@"MASUK Update");
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            DLog(@"MASUK Move");
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;
    }
```

with this code I make UITableView have animation when insert etc.. but I think its so fast.. I want to make it move slowly.. can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap your calls to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` in calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. I don't know of a way to control the animation speed though.

EDIT: This is not strictly true. I clearly don't know what I'm talking about. DO NOT UPVOTE.

Comment: not clear. why do I want to wrap my calls to insertRowsAtIndexPaths and deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: AFAIK, that's how the table view knows to animate the row additions/subtractions.

Comment: Ignore me. It obviously animates the table without begin/end updates.